# How to create Virtual directory using MSBuild Script?

Tags: msbuild, nant

Can anyone please help me in converting the below nant script to MsBuild Script?

http://localhost//Tupe path="${triad_web_src_code.dir}\T.csproj" />

If it is not a web solution then I need not map the solution & the msbuild could be like this :

But this is not working for Web project. So please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.Web.WebSite.CreateVirtualDirectory
              VirtualDirectoryName="SampleVirtualDirectory"
              Path="$(PhysicalOutputPath)"
              WebSiteName="$(DefaultWebSiteName)" AppCreate="True" /
```

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29209-MSBuild-Script-Sample-for-deployment-web.aspx

Should be what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) it has the `WebDirectoryCreate` task  that accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Bas. We have MSBuild Community Tasks already integrated to our project. We will use that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative the the approaches listed above is to create use Web Deployment Projects ([2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx) [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en)) for this. They support creating virtual directories as well a pre-compiliation out of the box.

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create both a virtual directory and an IIS application pool together you can do the following:

```
<Web.AppPool.Create 
        AppPoolName ="$(AppPoolName)" 
        IdentityType="NetworkService"/>

<Web.WebSite.CreateVirtualDirectory
          VirtualDirectoryName="$(WebServiceVirtualDirectoryName)" 
          Path="$(WebServiceVirtualDirectoryPath)" 
        AppPoolId="$(AppPoolName)"
          WebSiteName="$(WebServiceSiteName)" 
          Condition="!Exists('$(WebServiceVirtualDirectoryName)')"/>
```